# How to fread() 2 structs together C

Tags: c, file-handling

How do I display 2 `fread()` statements in 1 line.

Here is the part of my code:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("hello", "rb");

struct clientName NAME;
struct clientAge AGE;

system("cls");
if(fp == NULL){
printf("ERROR");
getch();
}
else{
printf("NAME\t\tAGE\n");
printf("-----------------------------------------\n");
while((fread((char *)&NAME, sizeof(struct clientName), 1, fp))==1){
    printf("%s", NAME.name);    
    while((fread((char *)&AGE, sizeof(struct clientAge), 1, fp))==1){
        printf("\t\t%d", AGE.age);
    }
}
```

When there is 1 set of data, the formatting is correct. But when there are 2 or more sets of data, it begins to mess up. I am really new to file handling in C. Thank you!

Comment: None of your inner-loop `printf` formats contain any newlines, so everything will be strung together on a single line (unless the data itself, stored in the structure fields, contains newlines, which I am highly confident they do *not*). And honestly, you never showed us(a) sample input data, (b) desired output with formatting, and (c) actual output with things "messed up", there isn't enough here to do anything but guess and speculate regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your format of text is as follows.

```
  name1
  age1
  name2
  age2
```

In that case what you need is.

```
  while((fread((char *)&NAME, sizeof(struct clientName), 1, fp))==1 &&
           (fread((char *)&AGE, sizeof(struct clientAge), 1, fp))==1){
             printf("%s", NAME.name);    
             printf("\t\t%d", AGE.age);
     }
```

Comment: `"rb"` in combination with `fread` of fixed structures. What makes you believe this is being read as any "format of text" ? I think your `while` multipart is correct (at least moreso than the OP's for sure) if the *structure layout* is as you've shown. And for that, have an uptick =P

Answer (score 1):

Turn

```
while((fread((char *)&AGE, sizeof(struct clientAge), 1, fp))==1)
```

into

```
if((fread((char *)&AGE, sizeof(struct clientAge), 1, fp))==1)
```

Otherwise you will read the clientName and then keep reading clientAge multiple times since the while iterates, because the file is not over. Of course the parsing will be invalid since your file contains data for name, age, name, age etc. Therefore attempting to parse the file as name, age, age, age etc. takes bytes that represent names and tries to parse them into age.